# Mathematical proof for lasso regression for correlated features selection

Tags: regression, lasso

I am wondering if there is a rigorous math proof for the behavior of lasso regression when there are correlated features? For example, I have features (x1, x2, x3, ...), if x1 and x2 are highly correlated, or exactly the same,
I think there will be multiple solutions. What relation will solution $\mathbf{\theta_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{\theta_{2}}$ have?

The loss function is
$J(\theta)= \left\Vert X\theta-y\right\Vert _{2}^{2}+\lambda\left\Vert \theta\right\Vert _{1}$

Comment: It is not true that if $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are highly correlated (but not identical), the non-regularised regression problem will have multiple solutions, there will only be one. The intuition (not a proof) is that if they are highly correlated, there will be two solutions, one where the coefficient of $\theta_{1}$ is 0 and where the the $\theta_{2}$ coefficient is zero, which aren't far off the optimal solution in terms of the loss value. Adding in the regulariser should make both of those solutions more optimal than the optimal solution to the non-regularised problem.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you mean by "behavior"?  Where you suggest "multiple solutions," do you mean to the OLS regression or the Lasso, and (regardless), what leads you to think there can be multiple solutions?